# Are there any information-theoretically secure verifiable secret sharing protocols with t=n?

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, verifiability

Disregarding matters such as efficiency and round complexity, can verifiable secret sharing be done in a way such that the secret cannot be decoded unless you have all n shares, and that this guarantee is information-theoretic?

Comment: What should be verifiable about the sharing? ​ ​

Comment: Verifiable secret sharing means that all the participants can verify that t shares will, in fact, reconstruct something intelligible. It's important if you're going to use it in something like MPC, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/verifiable_secret_sharing

Comment: Do you have a specific definition for "intelligible" in that context? ​ ​(Xhe wiki article describes it as the shares only needing to be consistent.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Is there a reason why the work in the [BDOZ](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/514.pdf) protocol, where they use additive secret sharing and an information theoretic MAC, wouldn't work?

Comment: Ricky, I mean exactly what the Wikipedia article says.

Comment: mikeazo I just read that paper. The MACs are information-theoretically secure, but is the secret sharing itself? The use of homomorphic encryption worries me in that regard. Having it be additive secret sharing is a plus, though.

Comment: "I mean exactly what the Wikipedia article says." ​ In that case, just start with any all-shares-needed scheme and modify it to replace invalids with some default value. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Why is additive secret sharing not working for you? If you share $s = s_1+\cdots +s_n$ then you need all the summands to reconstruct, and it is information theoretic secure. Is there something I'm missing about your requirement?

Comment: Daniel, it's not a VSS. Maybe there's a way of modifying it to be a VSS, though?